# May I say that my name is known "in a" lot of versions?

Tags: prepositions

I want to say that my family name has many versions. 
Could I say "The name of the family **is known in a lot of versions** such as Been, Bin , Veen, Vin etc."

The part of "is known **in a** lot of versions" is correct?

Comment: I wouldn't know why it should not be correct. It expresses an indefinite amount. What made you doubt about the correctness of the phrase?

Comment: Are you talking about a specific family or a general family name with many versions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The name of the family is known in a lot of versions such as Been, Bin , Veen, Vin etc.

Does not read correct to my UK ears. Variations that sound better to me are:

> The name of the family has many versions such as Been, Bin , Veen, Vin etc.
>
> The family name has many versions such as Been, Bin , Veen, Vin etc.
>
> There are many versions of the family name, including Been, Bin , Veen, Vin etc.

In each of the above "versions" could be replaced by "variations".

---

In a comment the questioner requested sentences using the word "known".

> There are many names by which the family has been known, including Been, Bin, Veen, Vin etc.
>
> The family has been known by many names, including Been, Bin, Veen, Vin etc.

Comment: I think "There are many versions of the family name, including Been, Bin , Veen, Vin etc." is the most natural one. The original is too wordy...

Comment: It's important to me to use the word "known" (e.g."It's known as... as well"